# How to compare value in foreach loop

Tags: java, loops, jsp, foreach

I would like to compare values in jsp file using foreach loop. I have array list with days of week but some of the repeat them selfs. I don't want to change the list. In jsp i want to print days without repeating them. There are any solutions using forecha, if or choose statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert the list to a set before iterating. It will remove all duplicates.

Comment: You could also recursively iterate through the Array List and use the built in "removeIf" method if the item your looking at is contained anywhere else in the list